# unexpected data declaration statement at 1

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, declaration, dimensions

I am trying to write a program that reads a matrix but when I use the `dimension` attribute to create the array, I get the error

> unexpected data declaration statement at 1

Here's the code:

```
write(*,*)'insert matrix order'
read(*,*)n
real, dimension(n,n)::a
end
```

What is wrong? I tried every other method to write an array, but nothing works.
The point is that it is like if the software does not understand what dimension stands for. The syntax is correct as you can see but gfortran say that there is an error. Can you please help me find the error? No it is not a duplicate of another question, if you look closely i'm asking a different thing from what someone mentioned. Help me please, don't ignore me.

I'm not having problem on the syntax as in the example someone showed me, but in the fact that fortran gives me an error that sould not be here because the syntax is perfect. Let me rewrite the question then: is the syntax of my code okay? Is it wrong? Explain me, please. I just want to create an array for a nxn matrix, but nothing works, neither static nor dynamic allocation because gfortran gives me ''unexpected data declaration statement at 1'' where the 1 is located under the letter ''a'' after the dimension declaration. Now, what did i do wrong?

Comment: neither dynamic allocation works, i get the same error

Comment: using dynamic allocation does not work, i also used the exact syntax in the post you have mentiones but no positive results, only the same error.

Comment: The point is that it is like if the software does not understand what dimension stands for. The syntax is correct as you can see but gfortran say that there is an error. Can you please help me find the error? No it is not a duplicate of another question, if you look closely i'm asking a different thing from what someone mentioned. Help me please, don't ignore me.

Comment: After reading your edit, did you actually read the link? It is NOT just about syntax. The point is that `n` is not known at the beginning of the program! Even if it was a constant, the the declaration must be at the beginning of the program.

Comment: There is more to syntax than just individual lines.  By itself `real, dimension(n,n)::a` isn't intrinsically wrong (and can be lexed).  The problem is _where_ that line appears.  If you look at the answer to the other question you'll see that even there the declaration line appears early in the code.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please give me an example? Anyway i tried with writing `integer :: n` before the write part but it gives me the same error.

Comment: problem solved. i just had to put dynamic allocation on top of everything and then, after 'n' was defined, allocate them. thanks everyone and sorry for my $%!£? attitude